# var/tmp folder taking up half my storage space?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, file-upload, local-storage, storage

I know this isn't really code related, but I don't know where else to ask?

While working yesterday I got a message saying that my startup disk was almost full. Which I wasn't too surprised by because it's only a 128gb Air.

But when I fired up Daisydisk to see what the issue was it appears that my computer has stored 2 files in the `private/var/tmp` directory, each over 30gb. Obviously Daisydisk won't let me erase them because of the directory they are in.

They are called `magick-23598T_US4im5XKvQ.pam` and `magick-23587vell8J7UTKgS.pam`

I have no idea where they came from, but I was testing a file upload system for a rails project when this happened. I was however uploading images over no more than 800kb or so. This seems a little extreme for that.

If anyone has *any* idea what might have happened, or how I can safely free up this space again, I would be massively grateful.

Comment: In answer to the question of where this belongs, probably SuperUser and maybe Ask Different, although it's a bit technical for that.   If it's in `/var/tmp/`, you should be able to delete manually or reboot the machine and it should take them out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like ImageMagick temp files -- are you processing the images with ImageMagick? There's a similar problem discussed [here](http://www.linux-archive.org/fedora-user/445901-strange-file-tmp.html) although the exact cause may be different.

Comment: Not ImageMagick, but RMagick. So I am guessing that it is being caused by the same thing.

Comment: AIUI RMagick is based on ImageMagick/GraphicsMagick, so that makes sense. Dunno if it's a bug, or something being called wrong... it might be worth looking at the timestamps on the files and see if you can figure out what triggered it, and see if you can adjust how you use RMagick to avoid the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely a large swap file from ImageMagick that hasn't been cleaned up.  You can limit the file sizes by editing your policy.xml config for ImageMagic (/etc/ImageMagick/policy.xml on Ubuntu).

More info here: https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=29225&p=130707#p130707